# Event listeners in jquery

Tags: javascript

I have written a javascript function named function1 and function2 and I am using it here below as onclick:

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="function1(); function2();" name="name1" value="">
<input type="checkbox" onClick="function2()" name="name2" id="name2" value="">
```

But if I want to add event listeners instead of onclicks, I am writing like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="name1" id="name1" value="">
<input type="checkbox" name="name2" id="name2" value="">

$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#name1").click( function(){
        function1(); function2();
    });
    jQuery("#name2").click( function(){
        function2();
    });
});
```

But this is not working. Am I wrong?

Please help.

Comment: Works fine here, problem must be somewhere else http://jsbin.com/puyit/2/edit

Comment: Works fine for me as well: http://jsfiddle.net/J4K8Q/. Please provide more information.

Comment: Is it because you forgot to put your JS code inside <script> tag,then you need improvement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `click` method is deprecated in newer version of Jquery try using `on`. Change

> jQuery("#name1").click( function(){

to

> jQuery("#name1").on('click', function(){

Its better if you do it like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#name1").on('click', function(){
        function1(); function2();
    });
    jQuery("#name2").on('click', function(){
        function2();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Larn a bit how to code :**

- Include jQuery
- Add your JS code inside `<script>` tag

---

```
<input type="checkbox" name="name1" id="name1" value="">
<input type="checkbox" name="name2" id="name2" value="">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#name1").click(function() {
       alert('test1');
       // or your function1();
    });
    $("#name2").click(function() {
       alert('test2');
       // or your function2();
    });
});
</script>
```